# Possible to host multiple bindings on WCF via URL rewrite or similar solution?

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I know that WCF services can support multiple bindings, but it would be much better for my situation if I could do a url rewrite and just let wcf think it's coming from the hostname it's already expecting.

I know almost nothing about url rewriting so before I delve into figuring out how to do it I just wanted to ask if this is actually going to be possible, and if so where's a good place to look on how to do this at the server level in iis?

Comment: Um, is this from the point of view of the client or server?

Comment: @User52784246 Well suppose I have a service located at `http://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc`. I want another developer to be able to put something like 'services' in their host file so that they can navigate to `http://services/MyService/MyService.svc`. The problem with doing that right now is that WCF, by default, doesn't allow multiple bindings so I can't bind 'services' to the same place that I've got localhost bound to. I would prefer to solve this through rewriting if that's a possibility.

Comment: You can use "localhost" (even if the computer is called `fred.acme.com`) in the server bindings of the **web.config** and clients would need to have `fred.acme.com` in their **app.config**.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @User52784246 Our service configurations specify the binding explicitly in the web.config. For development we use localhost. In production it would be something else. If the incoming request doesn't come from the hostname that was used in the binding specified in the web.config it won't work.